AWS Codeartifact pypi repo not installing packages uploaded with twine
I am trying to make an AWS-hosted PyPi env (with CodeArtifact) work. I set up a domain and repo and have used twine to upload couple of .whl files of our internal repos built with setup.py. So far so good, but when I am trying to pip install them, I get no joy.
I have followed AWS Codeartifact pip setup guide, and I have tried both straight login and manual (setting CODEARTIFACT_AUTH_TOKEN and changing pip to the correct URL). Pip seems to be looking in the right place but cannot find the package in the index. What am I missing?
pip install blahblah-utilities
Defaulting to user installation because normal site-packages is not writeable
Looking in indexes: https://aws:****@myorg-${aws_account}.d.codeartifact.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/pypi/our-main-repo/simple/
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement blahblah-utilities (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for blahblah-utilities

however when I list the packages via "simple" API, I do see at least one:
curl https://aws:${CODEARTIFACT_AUTH_TOKEN}@myorg-${aws_account}.d.codeartifact.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/pypi/our-main-repo/simple/blahblah-utilities/
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Links for blahblah-utilities</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>Links for blahblah-utilities</h1>
      <a href="0.1.673/blahblah_utilities-0.1.673-cp36-cp36m-linux_x86_64.whl#sha256=9faccc5e10ba069be3ab38a33989593cd2915915dd77a10f8bb5d67decd6f9fa" data-requires-python="&gt;=3.6" data-gpg-sig="false" >blahblah_utilities-0.1.673-cp36-cp36m-linux_x86_64.whl</a>
      <br/>
  </body>
</html>


Ok, so my issue was tags - cp36-cp36m in the filename. There are several way to build with specific/no tags which would be the right approach here apparently
